# Example: the probability of the intersection of three events factorizes but pairwise independence does not hold

Tags: probability, independence

Let us consider three events A,B,C.

We know that they are mutually independent iff:

1)
$$P(A\cap B) = P(A)P(B)$$
$$P(B\cap C) = P(B)P(C)$$
$$P(C\cap A) = P(C)P(A)$$

2)
$$P(A\cap B\cap C) = P(A)P(B)P(C)$$

Is there any example in which the condition 2) is satisfied but the 1) is not? Can you help me with this, please?

Comment: Let $C=\varnothing$ and $B=A$ with $0<\mathbb P(A)<1$. Then $$\mathbb P(A\cap B\cap C) = \mathbb P(\varnothing)=0 $$ but $$\mathbb P(A\cap B) = \mathbb P(A)\ne \mathbb P(A)^2 = \mathbb P(A)\mathbb P(B). $$

Comment: Thank you, good example. Why did not you post it as an answer?

Comment: http://www.engr.mun.ca/~ggeorge/MathGaz04.pdf

Comment: repeat of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3381545/are-those-events-independent/3381905#3381905 where the 2 answers include (hints to) 3 separate examples.